# Filter all PouchDB Documents whos ID starts with "ent."

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I'm currently making a database for a journal-entrys-app, using PouchDB.
Every journal entry can have multiple destinations and costs.
The current id naming system is ent.1-x for entrys, cst.1-x for costs and dst.1-x foe destinations.
I would now like to filter all jounal entrys whose id starts with "ent." .
Whats the best way to do so?
Or should I solve the document namin/typing in another way?
I want to do it using PouchDB querys, since I don't want to waste ram and processing power loading the entire database and filtering it using pure JS.

Comment: its about PouchDB, i will add that to the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix search can be done with `allDocs()` and `startkey`/`endkey`. Some examples are described [here](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-quick-search#autosuggestions-and-prefix-search).